# jquery error $ is not defined in javascript extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I know you might close this now, but please listen. I am making an extension with `jquery`. Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
   "manifest_version":2,
   "name":"Ad Killer",
   "description":"A Basic program for blocking ads",
   "version":"0.1",
   "background":{
      "scripts":[
      ]
   },
   "content_scripts":[
     {
        "matches":[
        "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js":[
           "content.js", 
           "jquery.js"
        ]
     }
  ],
  "browser_action":{
     "default_icon":"ad128.png",
     "default_title":"Ad Killer"
   }
}
```

Here is my `jquery.js`:

```
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
crossorigin="anonymous"
```

and finally my `content.js`:

```
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"

$(document).onload(function() {
    alert('It Works!!')
});

var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");


for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
    elems[i].hidden = true;
};
```

The problem is that every time I run this, it gives me the error `$ is not defined`, but I have already initialised JQuery. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not including jQuery.  You're including a file *called* jQuery.js that has 3 variables initialised in it.  Download jQuery and include *that file* in your extension.  Once you've done that, remove the `src` line from content.js and put jquery.js before it in your content scripts (so that it is loaded first)

Comment: Why don't you just load the JQuery script into your popup.html via `<script>` tag directly?

Comment: All js used on internal extension pages should be included locally if you don't change the default [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

Comment: @NullDev I dont have a popup.html

Comment: *Please* don't load jQuery into **every** page (`content_scripts` with your `matches`) unless you **need** to.  jQuery is 85kiB of minimized code. This is a significant burden with which to saddle *every single page*. What of those of us who have 100's of tabs open? While It is possible you really *need* to load jQuery, it is more likely that you are doing so for the convenience of saving a couple/few hundred characters in your own code by not using vanilla JavaScript. If that is the case (we have no way to know), doing so is a *very* poor trade-off from your user's point of view.

Comment: @Archer I downloaded `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` and got rid of the `src` in `content.js`, but the problem is not fixed.

Comment: Did you include jquery in your extension and correctly reference it `content_scripts` *and* make sure it was referenced before content.js?

Comment: @Archer yes and I found the problem thanks for your help

Comment: Would you mind explaining your solution, for future viewers?

Comment: @Archer what I did was I downloaded `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` from [this](https://jquery.com/download/) link and I included it in my extension and in my manifest.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as Maxim said, download the `jquery.js` file and make sure you include it in manifest.json. Also, make sure that when you are writing the `"js":[` part that you load `jquery.js` first

Answer (score 1):

I have made a chrome extension with jquery, what worked for me was to download the jquery file and include that in your manifest in the place of "jquery.js".